# How to convert system.collections.generic.list<className> to string

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, arraylist

Trying to convert database value to string I'm having trouble because its not convert the value but system.collections.generic.list

```
try
{
    var finalColor = await App.Database.getColorUser(_username);
    await DisplayAlert("COLOR", finalColor.ToString(), "OK");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    await DisplayAlert("ERROR", ex.Message, "Ok");
}
```

Database table :

```
public Task<List<UserColor>> getColorUser(string userNameColor)
{
    var query = database.QueryAsync<UserColor>("Select ColorUser From UserColor Where UserName='"+userNameColor+"'");
    return query;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FirstOrDefault` will get the first in the list or `null` if enmpty... assuming there is only going to be logical one result

```
public async Task<UserColor> getColorUser(string userNameColor)
    {
        var list = await database
                       .QueryAsync<UserColor>("Select ColorUser From UserColor Where UserName='"+userNameColor+"'")
                       .ConfigureAwait( false );
        return list.FirstOrDefault();       
    }
```

**Resources**

[Enumerable.FirstOrDefault Method (IEnumerable)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This method is not included

Comment: @Saruman QueryAsync returns a Task<List<T>> so you have to await it first ;o)

Comment: nor ToList() , its only ToString() but its get error

Comment: @Saruman that will not compile, please check the async/await pattern

Comment: @Saruman As long as you do not misuse **the ring** everything is fine ;o)

Comment: @SirRufo Still.. Nope.

Comment: Nope, what? Can you be more specific?

Comment: cannot implicitly convert type "App.UserColor" to system.collections.generic.list<App.UserColor>

Comment: You did not change the whole method only the inner part, right? Please when copy/paste then copy all

Comment: OK , and here , do i need to change anything

var finalColor = await App.Database.getColorUser(_username);
            await DisplayAlert("COLOR", finalColor.ToString(), "OK");

Comment: No you dont, you will get back one instance of "UserColor" which will be assigned to finalColor.

Comment: its continue to show : System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[App.UserColor], not the color(value) that i want to